# Can I use a transaction log to restore to a date before my last full backup was made?

Tags: sql-server

I have a massive transaction log backup, and I have a full database backup for the past few days. I can use the transaction log backup to restore *forward* if I restore an earlier date from the full backup, but I'm wondering if it's possible to actually restore *before* the date I choose to backup from the full date.

To be more specific, let's assume the transaction log contains 12/01 -> 12/12 (today), and the oldest full backup is 12/07, and I want to restore to a point at 12/02.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it should be (technologically). But the product does not offer that choice.

Maybe a 3rd party product can help. There are some who can read and interpret logs. They can restore data from logs. Not sure if they need a base full backup, though.